# Activate method in form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to submit a single text field in a form. I have this view:

```
@model SenecaFormsServer.Areas.Dashboard.Models.EditProductModel
@using SenecaFormsServer.Areas.Dashboard.Models
@using Seneca.SfsLib.Connectors

<div id="ConnectorSettings-MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS">
    <h4>@Resources.Entity.Product.SettingsForConnector: Mail product handlers</h4>
    @{
        MailProductHandlersModel mailModel = Model.ConnectorModels["MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS"] as MailProductHandlersModel;
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.Sender, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.Editor("MailProductHandlers_sender", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = mailModel.Sender, @placeholder = Model.CustomerConfig.DefaultSenderAddress } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.MailSubject, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.Editor("MailProductHandlers_subject", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = mailModel.Subject } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Reply to form submitter", new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.CheckBox("MailProductHandlers_replytoFormSubmitter", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    -->

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.MailMessage, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => mailModel.Message)
            @*@Html.TextArea("MailProductHandlers_message", mailModel.Message, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 15 })*@
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDF, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFYes) @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsChecked, true, new { @checked = "checked", @class = "pdfchecker" })
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFNo)  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsChecked, false, new { @class = "pdfchecker" })
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <div id="hideLable">
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.PdfMessage, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", @id = "mceu_61", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage)
        </div>
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("GeneratePDFFromHtml", "Product",  FormMethod.Post)) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="col-xs-12 padding-bottom-10">
            @*<a href="@Url.Action("GeneratePDFFromHtml", new { designId = Model.Id })" class="btn btn-primary enabled"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF </a>*@
            <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF</button>           
        </div>

    }
```

And I want to submit this part:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("GeneratePDFFromHtml", "Product",  FormMethod.Post)) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="col-xs-12 padding-bottom-10">
            @*<a href="@Url.Action("GeneratePDFFromHtml", new { designId = Model.Id })" class="btn btn-primary enabled"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF </a>*@
            <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF</button>           
        </div>

    }
```

and this is the action method:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]                
        public ActionResult GeneratePDFFromHtml(EditProductModel model, string data, string designId)
        {

            string customerSchema = SfsHelpers.StateHelper.GetSchema();
            //TemplateLibraryEntry entry =  GetTemplateLibraryEntry(designId, customerSchema);
            SubmittedForm sf = new SubmittedForm();
            string schema = requestSchema;
            customer_DbConnection db = new customer_DbConnection();
            RenderFormController renderController = new RenderFormController();
            renderController.GeneratePdf(data, db,sf);
            //return RedirectToAction(model.DesignId, "Prdocut/Edit");
            return Content("It works");           
        }


</div>
```

but the action method is not been triggered.

How to trigger the action method?

There has be created a PDF file from this textfield:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GeneratePDFFromHtml", "Product", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-group">
    <div id="hideLable">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.PdfMessage, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", @id = "mceu_61", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage)
    </div>
</div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 padding-bottom-10">
        <a href="@Url.Action("GeneratePDFFromHtml", "Product", new { designId = Model.Id })" class="btn btn-primary enabled"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF </a>
        @*<button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF</button>*@           
    </div>

}
```

and this is also the action method that has to been triggered and create the PDF file. But the method is not been triggered in the controller

The problem is that it is a partial view. So I solved like this:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnGeneratePDF').click(function () {

            var form = document.createElement("form");

            form.setAttribute("GeneratePDFFromHtml", "post");

            form.setAttribute("action", "GeneratePDFFromHtml");

            form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

            var hiddenField = document.createElement("btnGeneratePDF");

            //hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "search");

            //hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "product1,product2");

            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);

            document.body.appendChild(form);

            form.submit();


        });
    });
```

and the view looks like now this:

```
<form method="post" id="form" name="form" action="@Url.Action("GeneratePDFFromHtml", "Product")" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="hideLable">
                    @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.PdfMessage, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", @id = "mceu_61", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 padding-bottom-10">
                @*<a href="@Url.Action("GeneratePDFFromHtml", "Product")" class="btn btn-primary enabled"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF </a>*@
                <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGeneratePDF" name="btnGeneratePDF" formtarget="_blank" onclick="GeneratePDFFromHtml()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.GeneratePDF</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

but the url is now like this, after I press on the button:

http://localhost:51098/Dashboard/Product/Edit/GeneratePDFFromHtml?

what is ofcourse not correct. so how to trigger the method in the controller?

I get also this warning: Uncaught ReferenceError: GeneratePDFFromHtml is not defined

Comment: All your form controls are outside the form tag. There is nothing to post back to the controller method. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I edit my post Stephen

Comment: With your revised view, are you wanting to post back the value of `model.PdfMessage`? - in which case your method needs to be `public ActionResult GeneratePDFFromHtml(string PdfMessage)` - but you may as well delete all the other controls outside the form tags (they don't post back)

Comment: Yes, but the method in the controller will not be triggered

Comment: Just noticed you have a class name `tiny-mce` - are you using a html editor for property `PdfMessage`? If so, and the value contains html then you need the [AllowHtml] attribute (if on a model property) or the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute on the controller method - [refer this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/11/09/mvc3-granular-request-validation-update.aspx)